# Export my entire Aperture library into nested folders in the format YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: macos, aperture

I'd like to migrate my photo library out of Aperture, but still use it to edit photos.

I'd like to export the masters and the modified versions of all my photos into standard Finder folders in the format `YYYY/MM/DD`.

I can't seem to find any advice on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it could be great, you can't get both results.

- You can split your Aperture library into smaller ones by
  *consolidating* and *reprocessing* masters.

  **or**
- You can export your photos with the desired format (File > Export > Name format >
  Edit) and then do some shell/Automator scripting.

Maybe you can do both but, doing so, you have to save a copy of every photo you add each time exporting them as described above. Please note that this will (almost) double in size your photo library.